# Clean way to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\cos \left( \frac{2m \pi}{N}k\right)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation

Here's the identity:

> For $0 < m < N$, we have
> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\cos \left( \frac{2m \pi}{N}k\right) = 0
> $$

I know I can solve this using a variety of methods, i.e. anything described here: [How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro).

But what I'm looking for is a 1-2 liner type thing. I feel the argument for my progression is just so nice, there must be a super nice way to prove this? I was able to do it for the case where $\cos$ is replaced by $\sin$... But maybe I'm being too greedy.

(More background if you're curious, but I don't think it's necessary to know: This is basically a follow up question to what I asked yesterday; basically we're finishing up the second equation: [Clean proof for trigonometry identity? I know what the answer is, but I feel like there should be like a $1$-$2$ liner to compute this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4253444/clean-proof-for-trigonometry-identity-i-know-what-the-answer-is-but-i-feel-lik?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Comment: This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17967/291201) to the linked question is a short one-liner.

Comment: yep i think you're right! *facepalm* so actaully, that answer caught my eye too, but i didnt know what the commenter to the answer meant by 'extract the real and imaginary' parts...but i think now i do, seems like the answer below is doing exactly that!

Comment: @sweetpotato Yes, exactly. Extracting real and imaginary parts just means considering $a$ and $b$ separetely in $z=a+bi$. An interesting thing is now to note that $z=0$ if and only if $a=b=0$, which is what I used below.

Comment: gotcha. actually even better, your way proves both the sin and cos relations at the same time lol...so no need for separate arguments like i had before

Comment: @sweetpotato Exactly. By the way, if you want to respond to someone in particular use "@[username]" (which can be auto-completed by pressing TAB after you have typed @). Then the user is notified that you made a comment referring to them.

Comment: @mrtaurho ahh lol i totally forgot thats a feature. good to know, thx again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine that

$$
\zeta=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}N\right)
$$

is a non-trivial $N$-th [root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), hence satisfies

$$
\frac{\zeta^N-1}{\zeta-1}=\zeta^{N-1}+\cdots+1=0\,,
$$

with the fact that

$$
\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}Nk\right)=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}Nk\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi }Nk\right)
$$

to get the result for $m=1$. For arbitary $0<m<N$ the same works since the summands corresponding to $m$ are just powers of $\zeta^m\ne1$, i.e. still powers of a non-trivial $N$-th roots of unity.

Comment: roots of unity, ofc! dang hahaha this is really clean. thanks!

Comment: @sweetpotato Yeah, roots of unity are something to keep in mind :) Glad to help!